# Return IEnumerable with Linq based on choice

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out a way to solve this issue with Linq, does someone have any idea on how to do this? Trying to find this particular use case has proven to be quite challenging so I hope this question hasn't been asked before even though I suspect I just couldn't find it.

```
public class Test
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

public Test[] testArray;

public enum Choice { A,B, Both = A|B }

public IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable(Choice choice)
{
    //need to use Linq methods to return an enumerable based on choice
}

//e.g  testArray = { (1,2) (3,4) (5,6)
//calling GetEnumerable(Choice.A)
// 1,3,5
//calling GetEnumerable(Choice.Both)
// 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Everyone focused on the wrong aspects of my question, yes the [Flags] attribute is missing, yes the enum items should be a power of 2 to be used as Flags.
I already marked the correct answer which is to loop over the collection which is what I did before, I just didn't realize I could yield return a IEnumerable so Implemented an enumerator

All the other solutions use Linq but rely too much on instantiating new objects, for a lazy quick approach that is fine but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: If you want to use bitflags with an enum, your values must be powers of two (or combinations thereof). You should have `Choice.A == 1` - currently it is zero, and `Choice.B` is 1. Therefore `A|B` will also be `1`, i.e. it has the same value as `B`. That's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on single Linq query, you can try `SelectMany` where you can return a required *collection* to be flatten e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable(Choice choice) => testArray
     .SelectMany(item => choice == Choice.Both ? new int[] {item.A, item.B} :
                         choice == Choice.A ? new int[] {item.A} :
                         choice == Choice.B ? new int[] {item.B} :
                                              new int[] {});
```

However, I'd rather implement a simple `foreach` loop *without any Linq*:

```
// Since you use bit combinations, let's do it explicit with [Flags] attribute
[Flags]
public enum Choice { 
  None = 0, // let have "None" explicit
  A    = 1,
  B    = 2, 
  Both = A|B 
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable(Choice choice) {
  foreach (var item in testArray) {
    if (choice.HasFlag(Choice.A))
      yield return item.A;

    if (choice.HasFlag(Choice.B))
      yield return item.B;
  }
}
```

Comment: To use the `HasFlag` the enum needs `FlagsAttribute`. Also the Both value would be obsolete.

Comment: @radoslawik: It will work either with or without `[Flags]` but you are right, `Choice` wants `[Flags]`. `Choice.Both` is not obsolete, it can be convenient to call `var data = GetEnumerable(Choice.Both);`

Comment: Why check choice inside the foreach loop? seems useless compute time to check it for each item.

Comment: @Rand Random: the overhead (`&` followed by comparison with `0`) is *negligible*, but the alternative (several loops) are less readable and maintainable. That's why I checked inside the (single) loop. Imagine that we have `Choice` which can be `A, B, C, D, E, F` with combinations `All, FirstThree, LastTwo, MiddleFour`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I feel like it defeats the purpose of flags, I would just create a variable `var both = Choice.A | Choice.B` instead. If you keep `Both` in the enum you can run into the situations where the choice maybe be equal to A | B | Both

Comment: @radoslawik: not really *defeat*: you'll be warned by *static code analysis*. We can't implement *method* (`Enum.HasFlag`) which complies on `enum` with attribute set (`FlagsAttribute`) and doesn't compile without

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I guess as long as `Both = A|B` and not the next flag value everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No Linq is needed, I would maybe use a `switch` expression (though there is a smattering of Linq in here):

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable(Choice choice)
    => choice switch
    {
        Choice.A => testArray.Select(a => a.Item1),
        Choice.B => testArray.Select(a => a.Item2),
        Choice.Both => testArray.SelectMany(a => new[] { a.Item1, a.Item2 }),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Invalid choice")
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres an inherit problem with your enum, A|B == B, so I changed Both to be it's own case. This solves the problem with one linq query:

```
public enum Choice { A, B, Both}
public class Test
{
    public int A;
    public int B;

    public Test(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tests = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test(1, 2),
            new Test(3, 4),
            new Test(5, 6)
        };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetEnumerable(tests, Choice.A)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetEnumerable(tests, Choice.B)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetEnumerable(tests, Choice.Both)));

        /*
         * Console Output:
         *     1, 3, 5
         *     2, 4, 6
         *     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
         */

    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable(IEnumerable<Test> data, Choice choice)
        => data.SelectMany(d => choice switch
        {
            Choice.A => new List<int> { d.A },
            Choice.B => new List<int> { d.B },
            Choice.Both => new List<int> { d.A, d.B },
            _ => throw new ArgumentException($"No case exists for Choice enum {choice}")
        });

}
```